# Retrieving pages with multiple tags using REST API

Tags: api, rest-api, wp-api

I'm having some difficulty understanding syntax to make a call from my application to the wordpress REST API when it it comes to getting pages that contain multiple tags.

I have no problem with doing a call like

```
 https://example.com/cms/wp-json/pages?filter[tag]=L1
```

but I am unsure of how to call the API if I want to filter on posts that contain the tag `L1 AND L2 AND L3`, etc....

Comment: hmmmm, pages usually don't have tags

Comment: @MarkKaplun , or using /posts? ... the content seems to be spread between posts & pages.  But I'm just trying to figure this tag issue out.

Comment: @MarkKaplun is right, but for posts AFAIK `posts?filter[tag]=L1` should work. Besides, if you are querying for pages, shouldn't it be something like `posts?type[]=page&filter[tag]=L1`. You probably should give the [WP API Documentation](http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-posts) another read. I've recently found an interesting [article series about the WP API](http://torquemag.io/?s=json+rest+api), maybe that will help you too.

Comment: BTW look into `tag__and` for querying posts tagged with multiple specific tags.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Tags aren't exposed for pages by default, but it's not hard to add them, or any custom taxonomy, to any post type. The WP API should support any mix of post types and custom taxonomies, IMO. It looks like the proper syntax for AND is `/posts?type[]=page&tag[]=tag1&tag[]=tag2` Not sure how to do an OR query, though.

Comment: Re-reading the documentation, my example is clearly wrong. I wonder if `posts?type[]=page&filter[tag]=L1&filter[tag]=L2` would work?

Comment: That should work. Please, post it as answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem but for posts. I found how to OR or AND tags together here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters

To get entries that have both `L1` AND `L2` AND `L3` ; use plus (+)

```
https://example.com/cms/wp-json/pages?filter[tag]=L1+L2+L3
```

In case somebody else comes along and wants to OR terms together I'll save you the trouble: To get entries that have either `L1` OR `L2` OR `L3` ; use comma (,)

```
https://example.com/cms/wp-json/pages?filter[tag]=L1,L2,L3
```

I have only used this with posts but it *should* work for pages too.

Comment: FYI for anyone looking at this in the future, I don't think this is valid anymore. After moving the plugin code to the WP Core, it looks like you'll need a query parameter `tag` with the tag ID's now.